# Long running python process - how to keep current date updated after 24 hours of runtime?

Tags: python, date, daemon

I have a python Daemon that runs continuously and hopefully never stops. It's being monitored by supervisord. However when the current date switches to the following day the following variable stays as yesterday's date:

```
today = datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y%m%d")
```

Any ideas on how to correct this and make the date keep up? The current workaround is to schedule a cron task to restart the service and it grabs the new date. Even though that takes a few seconds it could interrupt the users so I want to come up with a better solution.

Comment: Is there a point in the process where you could recheck the current date?

Comment: Can you not reset the variable in the body of your code?

Comment: If it has to be kept current, why not use the function call directly instead of saving a reference? Are you using it so often that the performance hit is noticeable?

Answer (score 4):

Variable assignments don't auto-magically update themselves.

Why not simply re-run the statement you showed each time you might need to refer to the current date? Or perhaps on each pass through your main loop, if you're referring to it **thousands** of times a second and repeated calls might degrade performance.

Comment: It's en eventlet app. I don't want to make the main loop check it every time because the main loop is basically a listener and it would be updating the date over and over again for no reason. Maybe I am thinking about this wrong though. I did what tigerhawkT3 suggested in the comment to my question and we'll see if it works tomorrow.

Comment: If you're trying to make your program wake up as little as possible, not checking the date until you're going to use it, as @TigerhawkT3 suggested, seems to make a lot of sense.